# How to auto indent in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-14

I need to indent multiple files in WebStorm. Its option **"Auto-indent"** in the **Code** menu only indents current line.

How do I use it on multiple files like I can use "**Reformat Code**"?

Comment: AFAIK -- only one file at a time. P.S. It works not with "current line" .. but with selection. And if no selection is present then it applied to current line only.

Comment: You're right, its working on selection. Dont know why it didnt work earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the folder you want to reformat the code for in the Project tool window. Then select `Code | Reformat Code`

This page explains it. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/reformatting-source-code.html
[image: Reformat Code]

Comment: I am asking how can i auto indent like i can reformat. Reformat is not indenting lines in webstorm. Its making me go line by line

Comment: @DushyantBangal It does .. because it's more complex task and indenting is just one of the steps. It's just possible that with new reformatted code the indenting may be not needed or produce different/undesired result (as reformatting may split or join lines etc). You better provide concrete code samples of what's not working/working wrong.

Comment: @LazyOne yes, its working. Dont know what happened earlier. I had fired code reformat on the file, it didnt indent. Even selection did not work. had to do it line by line. Its working now